# Plotly not loading fig when `fig.show()` called

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to make and show a `distplot` plotly figure in the PyCharm IDE but the browser it tries loading in seems to buffer forever. My data and chart is as such:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

hist_data = 
[[23740.0, 66440.0, 47890.0, 40632.0, 51778.0, 59966.0, 92433.0, 101595.0, 53863.0, 27279.0, 49620.0, 14981.0], 
[32566.0, 95661.0, 69957.0, 62255.0, 73688.0, 90606.0, 163077.0, 151885.0, 80432.0, 39790.0, 76275.0, 23061.0], 
[41811.0, 122388.0, 87849.0, 80795.0, 98960.0, 123870.0, 245555.0, 204934.0, 105540.0, 49233.0, 98183.0, 29583.0]]


# Group data together
group_labels = ['1997', '2007', '2017']

fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.2)
fig.show()
```

I don't think it's a problem with the code it seems to be something to do with calling the figure. The code is for reprodicibility. If anyone knows how to debug this that would be great.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you using a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Nah I'm using PyCharm IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the lack of drawing is that the binning numbers are too small and require a large amount of calculation and freeze. I adjusted the `bin_size=10000` appropriately, and it shows up.

```
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=10000)
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with a different dataset and does not seem to be a problem with the small numbers. I am using spyder